# Soccer data set with time stamps for goals

Tags: data-request

There are many open source data sets available on soccer match data, but I have come across none which offer time stamps for goals specifically.

If someone could provide such a data set, I will be very grateful.

Comment: which ones have you checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[football.db](http://openfootball.github.io/) offers (historical) "free open public domain football data" including information on timestamps refined to the conventional minute level.  Example schema for matches:

```
### Matches

Quarter-finals - 1st Leg

[Tue Apr/1]
  20.45   FC Barcelona        1-1  Atlético Madrid     @ Camp Nou, Barcelona
            [Neymar 71'; Diego 56']
  20.45   Manchester United   1-1  Bayern München      @ Old Trafford, Manchester
            [Vidić 58'; Schweinsteiger 67']
[Wed Apr/2]
  20.45   Real Madrid         3-0  Borussia Dortmund   @ Santiago Bernabéu, Madrid
            [Bale 3' Isco 27' Ronaldo 57']
  20.45   Paris Saint-Germain 3-1  Chelsea FC          @ Parc des Princes, Paris
            [Lavezzi 4' Luiz 61' (o.g.) Pastore 90+3'; Hazard 27' (pen.)]
```