# Where to get soccer data per period?

Tags: data-request, sports, time-series

I have searched for period data in soccer - like number of goals in 15,30,45,60,75,90 mins (15 minutes interval) - but I can't find any. Do you know any site giving this data?

[Reposted](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/24501/where-to-get-soccer-data-per-period?noredirect=1#comment33538_24501)

Comment: Data on timestamped goals exists (see [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/15985/7031)) but you might need to do a bit of aggregation to get the interval format you're after.

Comment: Hello, I wonder the specific dataset where to get the data for 15mins interval. All of them seems to be on full time total goals. Can you help me?

Comment: I'm not aware of any dataset that aggregates goals to 15 minute intervals.  The alternative I'm suggesting would require you to use the Ruby Gem [sportdb](https://github.com/sportdb/sport.db/tree/master/sportdb) to build the [football.db](https://github.com/openfootball/quick-starter) database locally.  The resulting database will have a [schema](http://openfootball.github.io/schema/) that includes goals with minute timestamps.  From there you would need to manually aggregate goals in a match to 15 minute intervals.

Comment: I closed this because the aggregation to 15-min bins should be easy enough.